# Remove element (both from client and server ) that I just added with Ajax - MVC3

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I have a view where I add some elements to a table from Database; let's call the table Students. On the view I also have the option to assign to the student I am adding to the table some books . I have done this with Ajax.

Demo:

```
    Name of Student: ...
    Books : <here is a drop down> ( from database)    < here is a button> (add button)

    <ul>
   When I click the button here I append some books. I also retain on Session the id of every book ( in a list and when I click submit I send that list to the server )
    </ul>
[Submit button]
```

The problem is that I want to add a delete buton too like this :

```
    Name of Student: ...

    Books : <here is a drop down>     < here is a button> 

    <ul>
    Book1  delete
    Book2  delete
    </ul>
[Submit button]
```

And when I click the delete button to remove that element from the list and from the Session.

Here is my code:

- Script from the View

  ```
  $(function () {

      $("#add").click(function () {

          //items.push($("#category").val());
          $.ajax({
              url: '@Url.Action("AddCategory")',
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "JSON",
              data: { id: $("#categoryId option:selected").val() },
              beforeSend: function () { },
              success: function (data) {

                  $("#toFill").append("<li>" + $("#categoryId option:selected").text() + " " + "<span style='cursor:pointer;' id='a'>" + "[X]" + "</span>" + " " + "</li>");
              },
              error: function () { alert("error") }

          })
          $("#toFill #a").click(function () {

              $.ajax({
                  url: '@Url.Action("DeleteCat")',
                  type: "POST",
                  dataType: "JSON",
                  data: { id: $("#categoryId option:selected").val() },
                  beforeSend: function () { },
                  succes: function (data) {
                      // $("li").remove();
                      alert("lala"); return false;
                  },
                  error: function () { alert("error at delete") }



              })

          });
      })
  ```
- `AddCategory` and `DeleteCat` from Controller:

  ```
  public ActionResult AddCategory(int id)
  {
      Session.Category.Add(id);
      return Json(id, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }

  public ActionResult DeleteCat(int id)
  {
      Session.Category.Remove(id);
      return Json(id, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be more logical and easier to follow, use and program if you have one delete button acting on the drop down directly - i.e. select an item in drop down and click delete to delete the selected item.

Comment: I'm not thinking at that. You see... let's say you have a Virtual Shop and for each Category you assign more products.  You select one product from dropdown than you click add ; you select another product from dropdown than you click add again . Now you realized that you don't need the first product you have added and you click the delete button. Now in the list you have only the second product and when you click submit, in the table is registered only the second product.